# Not allowed to select option after selecting All in jquery chosen

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I have used Jquery Chosen plugin.I have fill up the data dynamically in drop down list.

I have allowed to select multiple option.But my question is that if user select All option then not allowed to select other option.If user remove selection of all then allow.

Jquery Chosen : http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

```
<select id="test" data-placeholder="Select Department..." class="chzn-select" multiple tabindex="6">
    <option value=""></option>  
    <option value="-1">All</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Any update ? I have tried below answer code but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that's easy .. all you have to do is deselect everything but the All option each time a use selects something... here goes the code:

```
//first we cache the all option selector
var theAllOption = $('#test option[value="-1"]');
$("#test").on({
    change: function() {
        var element = $(this);
        //if the all option is selected we find all the selected options and deselect them
        if (theAllOption.is(":selected")) {
            element.find("option:selected").not(theAllOption).removeAttr("selected");
        }
    }
});​
```

A working example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/senegalo/EKvUE/3/

A Working Example With Chosen plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/senegalo/EKvUE/4/

Comment: this is not working with jquery chosen. I need work jquery chosen plugin

Comment: @Harry Sorry .. i though you wanted an alternative to Chosen ... anyway here is a tweaked version to work with chosen "you simply have to trigger the update on the element"

Comment: @AspiringAqib it's working fine on my end... try the new version i appended to my answer.. if it's not working.. let me know also let me know which browser you are using and which version :)

Comment: @KarimMagdyMansour I am using chrome latest version.I have see your chosen plugin example on fiddle.I have updated my code as per your example and inform you